# Php javascript not show data

Tags: javascript, php

hell, here i have a script...

my code is correct work fine but i make with .htaccess

when i type like this localhost/messages.php?hash=15717 javascript show correct data from database (See Image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UYMi.jpg )

but when i type like this localhost/messages/15717 not show data where is problem (See Image - imgur.com/dxIc5M8.jpg )

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^messages/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)(\/|)$ messages.php?hash=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

main.js

```
function getChatText()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/refresh.php?lastTimeID="+lastTimeID
    }).done(function(data)
    {
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
        var jsonLength = jsonData.results.length;
        var html = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonLength; i++)
        {
            var result = jsonData.results[i];
            html += "<div class='MessageMenuLeftUsers'><img style='float: left; margin-right: 5px;' width='40' height='40'/><div><a>" + result.from_id + "</a><div style='float: right;'>" + result.chattime + "</div></div> <div style='margin-right: 10px; margin-left: 45px; margin-top: 2px; font-size: 12px; word-break: break-all;'>" + result.chattext + "</div> </div></div>";
            lastTimeID = result.id;
        }
        $('#view_ajax').append(html);
    });
}
```

and index.php

```
<div id="view_ajax"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might not have modRewrite enabled.

I don't know your environment, but if you check to make sure mod_rewrite is enabled on apache, a quick google search should show you how, then your htaccess code should work just fine.